# Swing, Jtable , JDBC

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, resultset

```
  package com.officelog.manager;

  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.util.*;


  public class AdminControl implements Runnable{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AdminControl();
}

Thread t = null ;
int hour ,minute,second ;
int year,month,day ;
int Month ;


private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Admin_Control");
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label,name,date,time;
JTable table ;
JScrollPane scrollpane ;
public AdminControl() {
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(panel);

    panelSetUp();

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
private void panelSetUp() {
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1,Color.white,   Color.white));



    time = new JLabel();
    panel.add(time);
    time.setBounds(20, 25, 70, 25);

    date = new JLabel();
    panel.add(date);
    date.setBounds(20, 75, 70, 25);

    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();

    name = new JLabel("Name:");
    panel.add(name);
    name.setBounds(20,50,50,25);

    label = new JLabel("SuperUser");
    panel.add(label);
    label.setBounds(60, 50, 70, 25);
    label.setForeground(Color.blue);


    tableSetUp();
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.add(menuBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    menuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.gray, Color.gray));

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(file);

    JMenu source = new JMenu("Source");
    menuBar.add(source);
}
public void run(){
    try{
        while(true){
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR); 

            Month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            month = Month + 1;

            day = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
            displayDateTime();
            time.repaint();
            date.repaint();
            t.sleep(1000);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void displayDateTime(){
    time.setText(hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
    date.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+ year);
}

private void tableSetUp(){
    int row ;

    Object [][] data ={
            {new Integer(5),"Deepak","Deepak"
                ,"2013-21-03"
            }
    };
    String columnNames []={"EmployeeID" , "EmployeeName",
            "EmployeePassword","CreatedOn"};
    table = new JTable(data , columnNames);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    panel.add(scrollpane);
    scrollpane.setBounds(50, 200, 600, 100);
    table.setBounds(50, 100, 600, 100);
    table.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    table.setGridColor(Color.pink);

}
```

}
Can any body tell me how to insert data into  a JTable form a database. Here's my code which is incomplete.I have created a table but I have no idea how to insert data into it form a database in grid format, So that it ll be possible to edit the data form the table and update it in the database.Thanks for your time and consideration

Comment: Well I know how to retrieve data from the database but I couldn't figure out how use the TableModel to insert the data into the table.

Comment: Did you googled about your questions?

Comment: how comes that none of links at the trailing edge of this page helped you to at least a starter? You did read them (at least those containing jdbc/database in their title), didn't you?

Comment: unrelated: a) don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, that's the exclusive task of the LayoutManager b) access to swing compoenents _must_ happen on the EDT (anyway, what has the part updating the label with the current time has to do with your problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, The Save JTable column names as a `String Array` and data as `two dimensional array of any type`. You can fill the data array by retrieving the data from the database.

Following link has an example (no database)

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/ScrollableJTable.shtml

Following is the Oracle guide, which is really good.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: do you think If I do that it ll be possible to edit update or delete the  table or any specific value , which in turn , update the database as well...

Comment: The links contain the way of editing/inserting values to JTable. The rest is up to your application logic

Comment: a) the roseindia reference it completely unrelated (and so trivial and at the same time convoluted that it hurts, as they often are, IMO) b) the tutorial link is unrelated as well, though always a good starter